# How to group "Year" columns with number values in a XLS file

Tags: microsoft-excel

Here is how my file looks like:

[image]

I am trying to transform the data in order to get the following:

[image]

The procedure is not called "Transpose" and that is the reason why I am not using the term. The pivot process has not been useful so far. First, I am trying to find the best name/tags that describe what I am trying to do. Then, my target is to check whether that can be done in Excel or a script (Python etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power Query to get the result, follow these steps:

[image]

Comment: Power query does not exist on mac :(

Comment: Is there a way to do that in a Pivot table?

Comment: No~ I don't find a way in PivotTable. Because there are null values for Country and Gender column.